# Validating user input Angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am using Angular forms for the first time. I am trying to create a form which will validate input. I cannot seen to get it working. I get the error "property name does not exist on type RegisterComponent". I feel like I missed something but all tutorials are showing only this. here is my code :

```
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <p>Fill in all the fields to register</p>
      <hr>
      <form ng-app="app" name="registerForm">

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel required minlength="3" maxlength="30">
        <div *ngIf="name.$invalid && (name.touched || name.dirty)" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show your type script file please. Also, have you wrraped the form with `form` tags?

Comment: when use template drive form and validation, you create a template reference variable and eaul to ngModel, e.g. `#myname="ngModel"`. is **this** myname the variable that you use, Angular don't take account the "id" or the "name", only the "template reference variable". You can see in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation. NOTE: check any way the Reactive Forms -is another way to create the forms, this offer more versability-

Answer (score 0):

Some property value is not getting binded properly. Try this code once.

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">firstName</label>
      <input formControllerName="firstName" type="text" maxlength="255" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': firstName.invalid && firstName.dirty}"/>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
          firstName is required
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

TS code:

```
    registerForm: FormGroup;
       ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          firstName: [this.registerForm.firstName, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)])],
        });
      }
        get firstName() { return this.registerForm.get('firstName'); }

 var firsNameObtained = this.firstName.value;//on form submit
```